# Google Analytics Navigation Summary for specific visitor

Tags: google-analytics

After a person register on my site I would like to see the browsing history for it.
Navigation Summary looks good but is there any way I can apply this to an uniq visitor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

> PRIVACY . You will not (and will not
>   allow any third party to) use the
>   Service to track or collect personally
>   identifiable information of Internet
>   users, nor will You (or will You allow
>   any third party to) associate any data
>   gathered from Your website(s) (or such
>   third parties' website(s)) with any
>   personally identifying information
>   from any source as part of Your use
>   (or such third parties' use) of the
>   Service. You will have and abide by an
>   appropriate privacy policy and will
>   comply with all applicable laws
>   relating to the collection of
>   information from visitors to Your
>   websites. You must post a privacy
>   policy and that policy must provide
>   notice of your use of a cookie that
>   collects anonymous traffic data.

Copied verbatim from [Google Analytics Terms of Service](http://www.google.com/analytics/tos.html) (Number 7)